# Getting married to my Polish fiancee

Tags: visa, marriage, poland

I have my ceremony set and the date is ready. I just need a visa. My question is should I apply as a tourist normally or is there any other way to apply? Also, should I include the official paper from Polish government stating the date of my ceremony when applying to the visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Unfortunately, my nationality does not entitle me for free stay up to 90 days without a visa.
I hope that helps. @phoog

Comment: @Jad For clarity, are you talking about a visa to marry in Poland? And/or to move there? Knowing your citizenship would be useful eg if there are any requirements you need to fulfil in your home country

Comment: @Traveller I am talking about a visa to get married in Poland at the moment not Visa to move there